# MVC Context Menus Missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been following this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started on MVC 5. I've got as far as trying to add a controller, and when I right-click on controllers and choose "Add", I don't get some of the options in the picture - e.g. "Controller" or "New Scaffolded Item...".

I'm using VS 2013 Professional, and have uninstalled and reinstalled, tried repairing the installation, all to no avail. Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are facing Quango problem in here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623516/in-visual-studio-2013-asp-net-mvc-5-how-do-i-add-a-new-controller. He got his menu back after a re-install of VS 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: I have already done a full reinstall of VS 2013, and it still doesn't work =(